# My CSS files are not getting loaded from my S3 bucket, why?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here's my S3 configurations:

```py
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

I have a couple of models that have ImageFields and when I upload an image it properly gets uploaded to my S3 bucket.

But I also want to put my staticfiles there (JS, CSS). I have manually created a folder in the root of my S3 bucket called **static** and I have uploaded all of my CSS, JS files to that folder using S3's web app.

However, in my template I am simply doing *{% static 'css/main.css' %}* and the file is not getting loaded.

I used Chrome's inspect tool to check which resources are being loaded and I think it gets connected to my S3 bucket, but brings the file I want empty, so it is not getting loaded for some reason.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYKD3.png)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to double check that you setup a bucket policy on your S3 bucket allowing public read on the objects and also have to turn off Block public access on the permission tab. By default your Bucket is private with no public access, which means your web app cannot see it. If that is already setup, you will have to check and enable CORS, because Django is trying to access your static files from another domain

Comment: I checked all of that. I found out the issue. Whenever I upload a file it gets uploaded perfectly, but it returns a URL for me that is incorrect. It returns one that doesn't have my region in it, when I add the region everything works, but how would I add my region so django storages handles it correctly? I tried AWS_S3_REGION_NAME but it didn't work. I am on the me-south-1 region

Comment: I'm glad you got it to work, by default AWS uses us-east-1 as the region name. So if it is in any other region than that one you will have to add the correct region.